# Google Apps Script URLFetchApp Permission

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, permissions, urlfetch

I'm new to GAS and I struggle with the permission system.

I'm a normal Google drive user and I started a spreadsheet and tried to add some code to it. My code is working, but only if I'm in the code editor. I want to use the onEdit() function so it's important for me that it works within the sheet as well. When I ran my code in the editor for the first time it opened a new window where I needed to enter my credentials to allow the script, then it worked. If I do some changes to a cell in my sheet and the onEdit() function is triggered I receive an error message that says something like this(translated):

> Exception: You are not permitted to call UrlFetchApp.fetch. Required permission: `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request`

In the editor I displayed the manifest file and added the permission to the oauthScopes but within the sheet I still receive the message. This is how my code looks like (simplified):

```
function onEdit(e)
{
    var data = {
        'key1': 'value1',
        'key2': 'value2'
    };
    var options = {
        'method' : 'post',
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'payload' : JSON.stringify(data)
    };
    try{
        var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://a-working-url.com', options); //error happening in this line
        //some more data wizardry
    }catch(error)
    {
        Browser.msgBox(error)
    }

}
```

Any ideas how I can open this permission screen in my sheet or any hints how to solve it in a different way? I want to create a sheet with some code running in the back online. I want to share the sheet with some friends, tried it with Excel and VBA before until I realized that it's not working with Excel Online, so I switched to GAS.

Answer (score 7):

`onEdit()`, like all simple triggers, is bound by the following restrictions ([see official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions)):

> - *The script must be bound to a Google Sheets, Slides, Docs, or Forms    file, or else be an add-on that extends one of those
>     applications.*
> - *They do not run if a file is opened in read-only (view or comment)    mode.*
> - *Script executions and API requests do not cause triggers to run. For    example, calling Range.setValue() to edit a cell does not cause
>     the    spreadsheet's onEdit trigger to run.*
> - ***They cannot access services that require authorization. For example,    a simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail
>     service    requires authorization, but a simple trigger can translate
>     a phrase    with the Language service, which is anonymous.***
> - *They can modify the file they are bound to, but cannot access other    files because that would require authorization.*
> - *They may or may not be able to determine the identity of the current    user, depending on a complex set of security restrictions.*
> - *They cannot run for longer than 30 seconds.*
> - ***In certain circumstances, editor add-ons run their onOpen(e) and    onEdit(e) simple triggers in a no-authorization mode that presents some additional complications***. For more information, see the guide
>     to    the add-on authorization lifecycle.
> - *Simple triggers are subject to Apps Script trigger quota limits.*

The ones highlighted in bold apply to your question.

Basically, it boils down to this - `UrlFetchApp.fetch()` is a service that requires authorization, so you won't be able to execute it from your `onEdit(e)` trigger, even if you have its associated scope set in your manifest file.

Comment: @OP: So, you should use [installable triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Answer (score 2):

Use installable trigger instead and write your own "onEdit" function (with a different name) that you bind to your installable trigger.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers

This solved the issue for me.