# Auto Sync google sheets to firebase without button

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I used a tutorial to help me sync my sheets to firebase with the use of a SYNC button that activates the script. The SYNC button currently sits just in the middle of the spreadsheet. I want to sync the data from sheets automatically to firebase when there are changes made.

```
function getFirebaseUrl(jsonPath) {

return (
'https://no-excusas.firebaseio.com/' +
jsonPath +
'.json?auth=' +
secret
  )
}



function syncMasterSheet(sheetHeaders, sheetData) {

  /*
  We make a PUT (update) request,
  and send a JSON payload
  More info on the REST API here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start
  */              
  const outputData = [];
  for(i = 0; i < sheetData.length; i++) {
  var row = sheetData[i];
  var newRow = {};
  for(j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
    newRow[sheetHeaders[j]] = row[j];
  }
  outputData.push(newRow);
  }

  var options = {
   method: 'put',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload: JSON.stringify(outputData)
  }

  var fireBaseUrl = getFirebaseUrl("UsersSheets")


 UrlFetchApp.fetch(fireBaseUrl, options)
}

function startSync() {
 //Get the currently active sheet
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()

  //Get the number of rows and columns which contain some content

  var [rows, columns] = [sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()]

  // Get the data contained in those rows and columns as a 2 dimensional array.
  // Get the headers in a separate array.
  var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, columns).getValues()[0];  // [0] to unwrap the 
outer array
 var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, rows - 1, columns).getValues();  // skipping the header 
row means we need to reduce rows by 1.

 //Use the syncMasterSheet function defined before to push this data to the "masterSheet" 
key in the firebase database

  syncMasterSheet(headers, data)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, it would be ok to just define an `onEdit` function in your code, like this:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  startSync();
}
```

However, because you are making external requests via `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, this [will fail with an error](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55996667/3399890) about not having the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request` permission (gobs more detail about trigger authorization [here](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle)).

Instead, you need to manually create an installable trigger

This is reasonably straightforward.  In the edit menu for your code, go to your project's triggers:

[image]

Then, select "add a trigger" and create the on edit trigger, like so:

[image]

You should think about if you really want this running on *every edit* as the requests could be quite large (as it syncs the entire sheet) and run frequently (as you edit), however.

Answer (score 0):

When you make a change to a spreadsheet, its [`onEdit` event](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events) fires. So that's where you'd trigger that save with something like this:

```js
function onEdit(event) {
  startSync();
}
```

---

But since `onEdit` fires for each edit, this may end up saving a lot more than really necessary. So you may want to debounce to only save after some inactivity.

Something like this:

```
var timer;
function onEdit(event) {
  // if we're counting down, stop the timer
  if (timer) clearTimeout(timer);
  // starting syncing after 2 seconds
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    startSync();
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: Unfortuinately, a simple `onEdit` trigger has [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/#restrictions) on calling `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`, so this will result in the script not functioning properly.

Comment: Oh darn, I didn't know that. Which part of the docs covers that restriction (as I don't see it at first glance)?

Comment: Yeah, I was surprised too.  Its the "simple triggers in a no-authorization mode" bit on that page, but if you dig more you find [this page](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/editor-auth-lifecycle#authorization_modes) which has a table with it called out explicitly.