# Remove a row from a sheet and copy to another spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have managed to remove a row and place in a sheet within the same Google spreadsheet. However when I modify the script to copy a row onto a different sheet, nothing happens:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "CONTRACT REGISTRY DOCUMENT" && r.getColumn() == 58 && r.getValue() == "X") {
 var row = r.getRow();
 var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...');
 var targetSheet = destination.getSheetByName("NOT RENEWED");
 var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
 s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
 s.deleteRow(row);
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem here is that you're trying to access another file from your trigger (onEdit), but that is not possible because it'd require permission to change another spreadsheet: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions

According to a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55996556/google-apps-script-urlfetchapp-permission), an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#g_suite_application_triggers) is the way to go here.

In this case, you need to add something like this to your code and run it to create the trigger:

```
function createSpreadsheetOnEditTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('moveRowToAnotherSheet')
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onEdit()
  .create();
}
```

Based on this trigger, it is necessary to make a few changes to the original code you posted:

```
function moveRowToAnotherSheet() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = ss.getActiveSheet(); // Changed
  var r = s.getActiveRange(); // Changed
  if(s.getName() == "CONTRACT REGISTRY DOCUMENT" && r.getColumn() == 58 && r.getValue() == "X") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...');
    var targetSheet = destination.getSheetByName("NOT RENEWED");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, targetSheet.getLastColumn()); // Changed
    target.setValues(s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).getValues()); // Added to use setValues instead of moveTo
    s.deleteRow(row);
  }
}
```

Comment: @ mshcruz Thanks so much for your help, the code you wrote works perfectly! I did search yesterday and came cross suggestion to use a trigger but I am so new to Google script I have not yet studied or used "Trigger" so it would have taken me ages to sort it out myself. I so much appreciate your help, you made my day!

Comment: @Lost R I'm glad the answer was helpful! Please consider accepting it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

The `moveTo` method can only move data within the same spreadsheet. It is best practice to use `range.getValues()` and `range.setValues()` to achieve the same behavior in different spreadsheets.

```
function onEdit(event) {
  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "CONTRACT REGISTRY DOCUMENT" && r.getColumn() == 58 && r.getValue() == "X") {
 var row = r.getRow();
 var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
 var data = r.getValues();

 // please supply the destination file ID as parameter here
 var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('...');

 var targetSheet = destination.getSheetByName("NOT RENEWED");
 var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1);
 target.setValues(data);
 s.deleteRow(row);
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi Carlos. Thanks so much, now I see why the updated code failed (moveTo). However, I am using your suggested code but it is not working. Would you mind re-checking and let me know if I need to add one more line of code?

Comment: @LostR: Do you have more details on "it is not working"? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: No, there is no error message. When I add 'X' under the column 58 it just does not remove the row and move to another worksheet. Nothing happens. Not sure if I can share the file with you?

Comment: Copy from: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iDyEirUhdu5vfvriSuLDujItBZFtkh-Rshpb7dnsbUM/edit?usp=sharing                                                                           
                                                                                                                                  
 Copy to: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1GNGfi8ae5kYeMz7p5QO-uYkkJma193nGU7SB3d_gpoc/edit?usp=sharing